# How to display an image from a shared network drive in Kendo Grid ClientTemplate

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, image, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display an image in a ClientTemplate in Kendo UI Grid for MVC

Currently, this works just fine, when referencing a folder location in my solution

```
 columns.Bound(c => c.Title).ClientTemplate(
            @"<div class='image-class' 
                        style='background-image: url(../Content/images/#:data.Image#);'></div>
                        <div class='image-title'><a href='" + Url.Action("Action", "Controller") + "?ID=#:data.ID#'>#: Title #</a></div>");
```

But, when i try to replace the url with a network shared folder, the image is empty. I have tried a few different approaches, with no success...

```
url('file://SERVER/Folder/'#:data.Image#);
url(file://SERVER/Folder/#:data.Image#);
url(\\SERVER\Folder\#:data.Image#)
```

Is there a known way to display an image this way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I created a virtual directory in IIS, and instead of specifying the full path, I simply referenced the virtual directory. I just set the permissions on the virtual directory to allow "Read" permissions to everyone, because I don't care who looks at them.

If there is a better answer someone has, I am all ears.

Thanks!